# typedef struct syntax for C++ Windows Forms?

Tags: windows, forms, syntax, struct

i'm having trouble with syntax regarding c++ Windows Forms..

this is how you obviously do it in a regular cpp project: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/

but its not the same in windows forms :/

any help??

THANKS!

Comment: Windows Forms cannot be used in C++. You have to use a language that is compatible with the Common Language Runtime. Options closest to C++ are Managed C++ (deprecated) and C++/CLI. In either case, `struct`s are declared just like in C++ (except for when you need a `ref` or `interface` class).

Answer (score 0):

btw, i figured it out!

you must create a new class in the project...
call it,  Player.h

in the new class, you must instantiate the class like below
to make it a [managed class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/mcppintro01.aspx) so it fits well with the managed code
in the forms (notice ref class keyword)

```
struct markedPos 
{
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
};

ref class Player
{
public:

    Player()
    {
    }

protected:


private:

};
```

then simply in the forms.h file, you must include the new class like any other class:

```
#include "Player.h"
```

and all you have to do is make an instance of the player in your forms and it'll work like magic!  What i've learned: Do all your heavy lifting in the managed classes outside of the forms... which work just like your regular c++ classes...

cheers!

** You don't need to use managed code! if your getting problems with it, just remove 'ref' before class name